# Karaf Bundle picking up some old dependency

Tags: apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

In one of my bundle in Karaf I am having a dependency as mentioned below:-

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.arnabk</groupId>
   <artifactId>java-dogstatsd-client</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I updated the version of `java-dogstatsd-client` to `1.0.3` in `pom.xml`. Created the bundle.I am using a `KAR` packaging but after placing the bundle in Karaf. I am seeing it is importing version 1.0.1 of the library. However everything works as expected if I place my bundle with 1.0.3 version of `java-dogstatsd-client` in a fresh Karaf instance. Below is the import I am seeing from Karaf web console:-

```
com.github.arnabk.statsd,version=0.0.0 from wrap_mvn_com.github.arnabk_java-dogstatsd-client_1.0.1 (262)
com.mysql.jdbc,version=0.0.0 from wrap_mvn_mysql_mysql-connector-java_5.1.6 (270)
com.sun.jna,version=0.0.0 from com.sun.jna (264) -- Overwritten by Boot Delegation
com.timgroup.statsd,version=0.0.0 from wrap_mvn_com.github.arnabk_java-dogstatsd-client_1.0.1 (262)
```

Also checking `bundle:list` I am seeing version 1.0.1 of the bundle:-

```
karaf@root>bundle:list | grep dog*
262 | Active |  80 | 0                                  | wrap_mvn_com.github.arnabk_java-dogstatsd-client_1.0.1
```

Because my bundle is picking version 1.0.1 of the dogstatsd client I am getting `Method Not Found Error`

Can some one please let me know:-

1. Why dogstatsd-client 1.0.1 is getting installed even though I have
   mentioned 1.0.3 in pom.xml?
2. How can I make my bundle install and use version 1.0.3 version of dogstatsd-client?

Environment:-

- Karaf - 3.0.5
- Servicemix - 6.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving to `Karaf 4.0.5` under `Servicemix 7.0.0.M2`. I am not seeing the issue.